# securing a jquery ajax to php connection

Tags: php, ajax, security

my ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "save.php",
    data: {
        name: $(this).attr('name'),
        value: $(this).val(),
        id: <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) echo $_SESSION['user'];?>
    }
});
```

and in save.php i'm checking with this condition:

```
if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || $_SESSION['user']!=$_POST['id']){
    //then show an error
}
```

is this the correct method to prevent unauthorized call to save.php?

Comment: What specifically are you trying to secure against?

Comment: @Brad anybody can create a page with jquery/ajax  with the url being set to my website's save.php. that'll grant an unauthorized acess right? again i've heard somewhere about "cross-browser-forgery."

Comment: Remember that anyone can create a fake request outside of the browser, and spoof these headers easily.

Answer (score 4):

**In general..**

> Anything at the client side is insecure. Therefore, any script may be
>   called from anybody at any time using any set of parameters.

**Protecting specific script**

Therefore, we need to **prepare something at the server-side**, that verifies something as valid at a later point of time.

Let's call it a **security-token**. A security-toke needs to be **sufficiently long and random** string. The security-token need to be **non predictable**. In this case, only the server-side application can be the source of this token.

Save this security-token to the user's session and pass it along to the client. Associate the security-toke with the script call to be protected. Your session might have this property:

```
$_SERVER[ 'sys$securityTokens' ] 
  = array(
     'AHSsd67sdSJDH/D6wehsd' 
       => array( 'script' => 'sensibleScript.php',
                 'params' => array( 'kid' => 3, 'var5' => 12 )
               ),
     'KSD87sd78sdsfk(DDF/sd' 
       => array( 'script' => 'someOhterSensibleScript.php',
                 'params' => array( 'value' => 'welcome!' )
               )
     );
```

Note, that this structure **associates security-tokes with script-names and valid parameters** to be called later on.

If client needs to call the script using JavaScript, it passes the security-token back to the server.

**At the server side...**

If a sensible script request comes in and the correct security-token is part of the request, remove the security-token from the session and execute the script.

If a sensible script request comes with no security-token, reject the request.

Answer (score 1):

As i see what you are tying to do..

better do it this way:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "save.php",
  data: {
      name: $(this).attr('name'),
      value: $(this).val(),
      id: <?php if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) echo $_SESSION['user'];?>
  }
});
```

and in save.php check **with this condition:**

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) || strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest' ||  $_SESSION['user']!=$_POST['id']){
   //here you can show an error 
}
```

***This new condition will also check weather the request made was through ajax or not ?***

As you can see its not a real restriction of user. it would be better if you do it serverside. you can have a look at this [Restrict direct page access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867013/restrict-direct-page-access)

Its secure but there are more ways out there too..

Comment: i thought `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']` will check if the request was through or not.

Comment: yes you are right as as it check for http header. i am goin to edit it a bit

Comment: This is not secure as the `id` parameter is predictable so it would not guard against CSRF. It would be possible to POST to this script from another domain using JavaScript, checking HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH does not add security. Even without these problems there are further flaws: The output of the php variable in the script should be properly sanitised when output to guard against stored XSS (probably JS encoded and then HTML encoded in this case).